# Cannot dualboot into Windows after Creators update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I was a happy dualboot user with Ubuntu 16 and Win10. This morning I saw an update available, so I installed it. There was very long configuring process before restart. After restart, if I select **Windows 10** in the GRUB menu I am stuck on a blank purple screen where nothing happens. I don't know if it's a problem with Windows or it's problem with GRUB that it cannot find the correct way to boot Windows after this update.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a problem with Windows and as such off-topic here.

Comment: i get it that this is one possible thing. but since grub is purple and dos is black, i expect black blank screen on windows bug instead of purple blank screen. also after few failed boots MS usually 99% of the time offers bootrepair, but this does not happens now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Similar situation, you can fix it by reinstalling GRUB2, as with any similar dual boot problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears the Windows boot loader was broken since its re-installation fixed the issue according to OPs answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 4 failed boots I have booted into Ubuntu. Then I tried to set Windows boot manager as primary in BIOS, but it failed and loaded Grub, where I selected Windows 10, then it recognized errors, and restored Windows to its state before the update. So now it works, but I don't know why. Maybe BIOS settings affected something, or maybe Windows detected 5 failed boots and fixed itself.

Comment: Grammar suggestion: `I selected Windows 10 and not it recognized errors` -> `I selected Windows 10, then it recognized errors`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues on an Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot system with the Creators Update. Windows booted after the Creator update with an "inacessible boot device" error message and restored itself to the previous version.

The following worked at my system to finish the Creator Update.

I used the tool EasyBCD and followed [this procedure](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-the-windows-bootloader-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-ubuntu.html) to use the Windows boot manager instead of GRUB2.

Then I didn't put an entry for Linux, so no boot manager appeared during the Windows startup. The Creator Update could then be installed successfully.

Finally, I included the entry for Ubuntu again in the boot manager.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to AskUbuntu!
It seems like a nice and productive answer you provided, so I upvoted it. I did edit it a bit, though, for appearance. If you want to make to improve it -- which would be highly encouraged -- you could type in the steps from the external source so the answer is self-contained (the external source may disappear). To do so is the norm.
Again, welcome, and thank you for helping your peers!

Comment: Easy BCD Doesn't recognize Ubuntu Grub Bootloader (EFI). See my answer for similar question.  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910703/boot-menu-not-showing-at-startup-ubuntu-windows-10)